# how to make documents.docx readOnly in visual studio using RichTextBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

here is my code below, when it is debug then the document will open in Rich TextBox but it can be editable so I need it to be ReadOnly. can u please help me out.

```
void ImportWord()
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordObject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    object File = @"C:\Users\czu_ecu\Desktop\OAG-WORK\Management_Letter_Template1.docx" ; //this is the path
    object nullobject = System.Reflection.Missing.Value; Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application wordobject = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
    wordobject.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone; Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document docs = wordObject.Documents.Open(ref File, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject); docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
    docs.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
    this.richTextBox2.Paste();
    docs.Close(ref nullobject, ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
    wordobject.Quit(ref nullobject,ref nullobject, ref nullobject);
}

private void btnTemML_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //Handles the actions of the template button
{
    btnAdd_Finding.Visible = false;
    listView2.Visible = false;
    label8.Visible = false;
    richTextBox1.Visible = false;
    listView1.Visible = false;
    listView3.Visible = false;
    richTextBox2.Visible = true;

    ImportWord();

    listView1.Items.Clear();
}
```

Comment: I assume it is winforms and added in tags, if not remove it.

Comment: This seems a bit obvious, but have you tried: `richTextBox1.ReadOnly = true;`

Comment: ya i have tried that but is not working

Comment: Again a bit obvious, but what about `richTextBox2.ReadOnly = true;`

Comment: another query : how to download documents.docx in visual studio using RichTextBox?

Comment: I have created a button download for documents.docx in visual studio. Now I have to download that documents .docx of RichTextBox2. so can u plz me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code.

```
richTextBox2.Visible = true;
richTextBox2.IsReadOnly = true;
```